# how to delete cached page in rails app deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku

I have an app deployed to heroku that was working correctly. I uploaded some changes about page caching (just testing!) and now it's always serving those pages, ignoring my requests to clear the cache (`Rails.cache.clear`)

The cached pages are NOT created in `public` nor `tmp` so I don't know how to delete them or where they are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by waiting the required amount of time for them to expire...

Answer (score 1):

I know this might sound trivial, but did you do a heroku restart and simply restart your application?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did a `heroku restart` and no change :(